# Mysql Left Join And Sum not Working Correctly with group by month and year

Tags: mysql, join, sum, left-join, multiple-columns

I want to get a sum of total_amount and received_amt with group by with month and year on `mysql`.
But I am facing a problem. 
The problem is second table column sum not correct with group by month and year.

**Current Query**

```
SELECT t1.order_date,sum(IFNULL(t1.received_amt, 0)) as SumOfNO,
sum(IFNULL(t2.total_amount, 0)) as SumOfSM,
SUM(IFNULL(t1.received_amt, 0)  + IFNULL(t2.total_amount, 0)) AS Total
FROM `new_order` t1
LEFT JOIN
 (  select t2.sell_date,t2.total_amount, sum(total_amount) as Amount
    from sell_master t2
    group by YEAR(t2.sell_date), MONTH(t2.sell_date) 
 ) t2
 ON format(t1.order_date,'yyyy-MM') = format(t2.sell_date,'yyyy-MM')
GROUP BY YEAR(t1.order_date), MONTH(t1.order_date)
ORDER BY t1.order_date DESC
```

Example:

First Table: new_order

Second Table: sell_master

Table Structure:

**new_order**

```
+----------------------------------------+
|order_date(date) | received_amt(double) |
+----------------------------------------+
|2007-10-06       | 245                  |
|2007-10-06       | 310                  |                             
|2007-10-06       | 275                  |                             
|2007-10-06       | 300                  |
+----------------------------------------+
```

**sell_master**

```
+----------------------------------------+
|sell_date(date)  | total_amount(double) |
+----------------------------------------+
|2007-10-06       | 10                   |
+----------------------------------------+
```

**Current Result**

```
+---------------------------------------+
|order_date | SumOfNO | SumOfSM | Total |
+---------------------------------------+
|2007-10-06 | 1130    | 40      |1170   |
+---------------------------------------+
```

**Expected Result**

```
+---------------------------------------+
|order_date | SumOfNO | SumOfSM | Total |
+---------------------------------------+
|2007-10-06 | 1130    | 10      |1140   |
+---------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Your subquery is likely just bad; the sell_date and total_amount fields in its results will be effectively random choices from the values found in the records for the year-month pair grouping. Why are you even calculating `Amount` when it is never actually used.

Comment: You group by month and year, so you get one result row per month and year. Why do you select a date then? Which date is this supposed to be? As is, MySQL let's this slip and picks an arbitrary date withion each month, but shouln't you rather select year and month instead of such date?

Comment: Are you sure you're using MySQL? It doesn't have a `FORMAT()` function, it has `DATE_FORMAT()`. And the arguments aren't like `yyyy-mm`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use `SUM(t2.total_amount)` in the main query. You already calculated the sum in the subquery, you should use that. What's happening is that you're multiplying `t2.total_amount` by the number of rows in `new_order` that matches.

There's also no need to use `IFNULL()` inside `SUM()`, since `SUM()` ignores null values (most aggregation functions do).

The subquery should select the year and month of the date, so you can join on those directory, rather than using `date_format`.

And since you're grouping by month, you shouldn't select `t1.order_date` -- that will just pick a random day of the month from the group. You should just show the month in `YYYY-MM` format.

```
SELECT 
    DATE_FORMAT(t1.order_date, '%Y-%m') AS month,
    sum(t1.received_amt) as SumOfNO,
    IFNULL(t2.Amount, 0) as SumOfSM,
    sum(t1.received_amt) + IFNULL(t2.Amount, 0) AS Total
FROM `new_order` t1
LEFT JOIN
 (  select YEAR(t2.sell_date) AS year, MONTH(t2.sell_date) AS month,  sum(total_amount) as Amount
    from sell_master t2
    group by year, month
 ) t2
 ON YEAR(t1.order_date) = t2.year AND MONTH(t1.order_date) = month
GROUP BY month
ORDER BY month DESC
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e6a1e8/2)

Comment: nice try @Barmar but sorry, my first table sum goes wrong and second table sum is right.

Comment: I just added a demo link, it returns your expected answer.

Answer (score 0):

You want to select an aggregate results (sums here) of one table combined with a aggregate results of another. So build both aggregates, then join.

```
select 
  year_month, 
  o.total as sumofno,
  coalesce(s.total, 0) as sumofsm,
  o.total + coalesce(s.total, 0) as total
from
(
  select format(order_date, 'yyyy-MM') as year_month, sum(received_amt) as total
  from new_order
  group by format(order_date, 'yyyy-MM')
) o
left join
(
  select format(sell_date, 'yyyy-MM') as year_month, sum(total_amount) as total
  from sell_master
  group by format(sell_date, 'yyyy-MM')
) s using (year_month)
order by month desc;
```